# Please explain Bird's eye view in the KITTI test set performance evaluation table in the VoxelNet paper

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, lidar, kitti

I read this paper VoxelNet: End-to-End Learning for Point Cloud Based 3D Object Detection
(https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.06396) and I don't know what BEV means in the table.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9NZg.png)

I also asked ChatGPT, but I don't quite understand what he's saying.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBO5V.png)

I'd appreciate it if you could let me know.
thank you

Comment: ChatGPT was not trained to tell true things. When it does, it is by accident. ChatGPT was trained to have seemingly consistent answer. It was trained for form, not substance.

Comment: That being said, BEV means "view from the sky". You can detect cars from images taken from the dashcam of another car. Or you can detect cars from images taken from an helicopter. That are two different things, because car do not look at all the same from those two point of views. So, "Car from the sky" and "Car from the ground" are two different use case. Exactly as "Car" and "Pedestrians" are also two different use cases. Different enough to justify separated performance evaluation in the table (an algorithm that can detect cars from the sky cannot necessarily detect cars from the ground)